# Haskell Parsec: Undo a failed many

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I have some code here that works for parsing URI paths into a list of Strings. For examples `/user/home` would become `["user", "home"]`.

```
pathPiece :: Parser String   
pathPiece = do
      char '/'
      path <- many1 urlBaseChar
      return path

uriPath :: Parser [String]
uriPath = do
    pieces <- many pathPiece
    try $ char '/'
    return pieces

parseUriPath :: String -> [String]
parseUriPath input = case parse uriPath "(unknown)" input of
                   Left  _  -> []
                   Right xs -> xs
```

However, there if the path ends with another `/` such as `/user/home/`, which should be a legitimate path, the parser will fail. This is because pathPiece fails to parse the last `/` since there are no following urlBaseChars. I am wondering how you parse with many until it fails, and if it fails you undo character consumption.

Comment: A note on style, `do { x <- m; return x }` is equivalent to `m` (guaranteed by the monad laws!) so `pathPiece` can be simplified a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
pathPiece :: Parser String   
pathPiece = try $ do
    char '/'
    many1 urlBaseChar

uriPath :: Parser [String]
uriPath = do
    pieces <- many pathPiece
    optional (char '/')
    return pieces
```

You need to add a `try` to `pathPiece`. Otherwise, parsing the final `/` will make Parsec
think that a new `pathPiece` has started, and without `try`, there's no backtracking. Also,
unless you actually want to *require* a final `/`, you need to make it `optional`. The
function `try` does not do that.

Comment: Thanks for the help kosmikus. That works just right, and I learned a few things about Parsec ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `` many1 urlBaseChar `sepEndBy` char '/' `` here. See [sepEndBy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v%3asepEndBy) in Parsec.